# how to change android spinner looks

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

I am using a spinner in android project. Everything is fine. The only thing is spinner is not displaying the way I want to.

This is image it looks like:

[image: Bad looking spinner]

But I want it to look like this:

[image: Good looking spinner]

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to my code below .This code will generate the spinner appearance with a drop down arrow.it is achieved by

> android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item

specified by ArrayAdapter.
To change its style you can use different layouts ,that you can find [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.layout.html)

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Spinner spin;
    String spin_val;
    String[] gender = { "Male", "Female" };//array of strings used to populate the spinner
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);//setting layout
        spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_id);//fetching view's id
        //Register a callback to be invoked when an item in this AdapterView has been selected
        spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int position, long id) { 
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                spin_val = gender[position];//saving the value selected


            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        });
      //setting array adaptors to spinners 
      //ArrayAdapter is a BaseAdapter that is backed by an array of arbitrary objects
        ArrayAdapter<String> spin_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, gender);

        // setting adapteers to spinners
        spin.setAdapter(spin_adapter);
    }


}
```

screen.xml

```
<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

you get have this demo project here for your reference [here](http://blog.creatiosoft.com/?p=1194).

Hope this helps.